# Python Combining f-string with r-string and curly braces in regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Given a single word (x); return the possible n-grams that can be found in that word.
You can modify the n-gram value according as you want; 
it is in the curly braces in the pat variable.
The default n-gram value is 4.

For example; for the word (x):
`x = 'abcdef'`
The possible 4-gram are:

`['abcd', 'bcde', 'cdef']`

```
def ngram_finder(x):
    pat = r'(?=(\S{4}))'
    xx = re.findall(pat, x)
    return xx
```

**The Question is: 
How to combine the f-string with the r-string in the regex expression, using curly braces.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this string to combine the `n` value into your regexp, using double curly brackets to create a single one in the output:

```
fr'(?=(\S{{{n}}}))'
```

The regex needs to have `{}` to make a quantifier (as you had in your original regex `{4}`). However `f` strings use `{}` to indicate an expression replacement so you need to "escape" the `{}` required by the regex in the f string. That is done by using `{{` and `}}` which in the output create `{` and `}`. So `{{{n}}}` (where `n=4`) generates `'{' + '4' + '}' = '{4}'` as required.

Complete code:

```
import re

def ngram_finder(x, n):
    pat = fr'(?=(\S{{{n}}}))'
    return re.findall(pat, x)
    
x = 'abcdef'
print(ngram_finder(x, 4))
print(ngram_finder(x, 5))
```

Output:

```
['abcd', 'bcde', 'cdef']
['abcde', 'bcdef']
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works perfectly; may ask you what is the logic behind the 3 curly braces here? I don't get; although it works!

Comment: @AkbarHussein the regex needs to have `{}` to make a quantifier (as you had in your original regex `{4}`). `f` strings use`{}` to indicate an expression replacement so you need to "escape" the `{}` required by the regex in the f string. That is done by using `{{` and `}}` which in the output create `{` and `}`. So `{{{n}}}` generates `'{' + '4' + '}' = '{4}'` as required

Comment: This is a great technique when you want to embed patterns into other patterns (and aren't using the regex form of curly braces very much). Note that normally you should pass fixed strings through `re.escape` before embedding them into patterns, else some characters in the string might be interpreted as Regex metacharacters unintentionally.

Comment: @rjh you are absolutely right; in this specific case though n can only be a number so escaping it isn't necessary.