# In Pandas Dataframe error: nothing to repeat at position 17217

Tags: pandas

I am trying to use `str.contains` to identify elements of one column of a dataframe in another column of another dataframe. Here is the code:

```
pattern = fr"(?:{'|'.join(strategic_accounts['Account Name'])})"
all_leads['in_strategic_list'] = all_leads['Company'].str.contains(pattern).astype(int)
```

Here are the heads of both dataframes as well as position 17271 of the `all_leads` dataframe. I don't understand the error because it looks like there isn't anything abnormal at position 17217. Also, all related errors online seem to refer to `error nothing to repeat at position 0` which seems like it would be a different error since mine came up at loc 17217. Any insights appreciated! Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

This mock example works perfectly with the same code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Marc', 'Jake', 'Sam', 'Brad', 'SpongeBob']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'IDs': ['Jake', 'John', 'Marc', 'Tony', 'Bob']})

pattern = fr"(?:{'|'.join(df2['IDs'])})"

df1['In_df2'] = df1['name'].str.contains(pattern).astype(int)
```

Update:
I have managed to figure out that the error is referring to loc 17217 in pattern not in strategic_accounts df. Printing the loc 17217 in pattern returns `'*'`. I have tried to apply this function to `pattern` before inserting it into the `str.contains` and I can't seem to get it to remove.

```
import re

pattern = fr"(?:{'|'.join(strategic_accounts['Account Name'])})"
def esc_spec_char(pattern):
    for p in pattern:
        if p == '\*':
            re.sub('*', '1', p)
        else:
            continue
    return pattern
pattern = esc_spec_char(pattern)
pattern[17217]
```

New_Update:
I have applied @LiamFiddler's method of turning the string into a re.Pattern object and run it on a dummy df and while it does seem to escape the `*` it doesn't seem to find the `N`. Not sure if I made some mistake. Here is the code:

```
sries = pd.Series(['x','y','$','%','^','N','*'])
ac = '|'.join(sries)
p = re.compile(re.escape(ac))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Id' : [123, 232, 344, 455, 566, 377], 
                           'col2' : ["N", "X", "Y", '*', "W", "Z"]})
df1['col2'].str.contains(p, regex=True).astype(int)
```

Comment: Any reason you are using Regex instead of [pandas.Series.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)?

Comment: @liamfiddler Thanks for commenting! I am comparing lead objects to account objects and there are some instances where the account name has been modified after conversion from lead so they will still retain much of the same original string from the lead but with minor differences. In other words not an exact match so `.isin` won't work

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense. Is the function working for other rows, just not this particular one?

Comment: I'm suspicious there is a sneaky issue with your pattern string. Check out this answer on combining f-string and r-strings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61625479/12229158

Comment: @liamfiddler Thanks! so I tried just running it on elements up to 17216 and it still threw the same error. I updated the original post with an example of it working on two sample dfs. Maybe that will shed some more light?

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28606659/12229158) presents a similar issue. Is it possible the Account Names contain special regex characters that need to be escaped?

Comment: Hi @LiamFiddler, I have updated the original post with my findings but I can't figure out how to handle the special character now that I have found it. No worries if you're tired of working on this but if you have any suggestions I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

I realized that `re.escape()` also escapes the `|` delimiter, so I think the appropriate solution is to map `re.escape()` to the series *before* joining the names:

```
strategic_accounts['Escaped Accounts'] = strategic_accounts['Account Name'].apply(lambda x: re.escape(x))
pattern = re.compile('|'.join(strategic_accounts['Escaped Accounts']))
```

Then you can proceed as below with using `Series.str.contains()`. On your sample dataframe, here is what I get:

```
sries = pd.Series(['x','y','$','%','^','N','*'])
ac = sries.apply(lambda x: re.escape(x))
p = re.compile('|'.join(ac))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Id' : [123, 232, 344, 455, 566, 377], 
                           'col2' : ["N", "X", "Y", '*', "W", "Z"]})
df1['col2'].str.contains(p, regex=True).astype(int)

Out:
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
```

### Original

Ok, so based on the discovery of the special character, I think this is your solution:

First, we need to escape the special characters in the strings so that they don't mess up the regex. Fortunately, Python's `re` module has an `.escape()` method specifically for escaping special characters.

```
import re
accounts = '|'.join(strategic_accounts['Account Name'])
pattern = re.compile(re.escape(accounts))
```

Now we can proceed as before:

```
all_leads['in_strategic_list'] = all_leads['Company'].str.contains(pattern, regex=True).astype(int)
```

Comment: Ok @LiamFiddler thank you so much for all your help so far! I think we're getting really close! If you have time please see the new_update to the original post.

Comment: @JustinBenfit I'm having trouble following. Why do you want to escape 'N'?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want to both escape the `*` and match the `N`. `sries` simulates the strategic_accounts['Account Name'] series and `N` represents one account name in that column unless I'm misinterpreting my data. I want it to return true ( or 1 in this case) for `N`, and escape `*` but when I run it it returns false for each element in df['col2']. At least that's the way I understand it. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JustinBenfit I think I see the error; `re.escape()` also escapes the pipe `|`, so we need to figure out a way around that. I think the best way is probably to map the `re.escape()` function to the series and then join it using pipes.

Comment: @JustinBenfit see updated solution.

Comment: That is some awesome wizardry! I feel like my understanding of pandas has grown a ton just from watching you work through this! Thank you so much for your help @LiamFiddler!

Comment: Glad to help out!