# Check if a substring is in a string python

Tags: python, dataframe, substring, contains, intersection

I have two dataframe, I need to check contain substring from first df in each string in second df and get a list of words that are included in the second df

First df(word):

| word |
| --- |
| apples |
| dog |
| cat |
| cheese |

Second df(sentence):

| sentence |
| --- |
| apples grow on a tree |
| ... |
| I love cheese |

I tried this one:

```py
tru=[]
for i in word['word']:
    if i in sentence['sentence'].values:    
        tru.append(i)
```

And this one:

```py
tru=[]
for i in word['word']:
    if sentence['sentence'].str.contains(i):    
        tru.append(i)
```

I expect to get a list like `['apples',..., 'cheese']`

Comment: Please format your dataframes as [tables](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501/1185254) for readability.

Comment: thnx bro!) @alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to use [Series.str.extractall](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#extract-all-matches-in-each-subject-extractall):

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

df_word = pd.Series(["apples", "dog", "cat", "cheese"])
df_sentence = pd.Series(["apples grow on a tree", "i love cheese"])

pattern = f"({'|'.join(df_word.apply(re.escape))})"
matches = df_sentence.str.extractall(pattern)
matches
```

Output:

```
                0
    match   
0     0    apples
1     0    cheese
```

You can then convert the results to a `list`:

```
matches[0].unique().tolist()
```

Output:

```
['apples', 'cheese']
```

Comment: Thnx! it useful

Comment: I got an error: nothing to repeat at position 4503, can you help with it?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69586665/13577373), it's likely because of repeat characters e.g. `"*"` and `"+"`. Using `re.escape` seems to work.